# Showing that $x (1-x) y (1-y) (1 - xy)^{-2}$ is less than or equal to 1.

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y \in [0,1]$ and consider the inequality $ f(x,y) \equiv x (1-x) y (1-y) (1 - xy)^{-2} \leq 1$. One can show this easily by finding $argmax_x f(x,y)$ and then plugging into $f(x,y)$ to show that $\max_y \max_x f(x,y) \leq 1$. But I wonder if this can be shown using a more powerful approach? Is this an implication of some well known inequality or general mathematical result? My ultimate goal is to extend this to an analogous inequality for matrices.

Answer (score 5):

Just expand and compare terms.

> $0\leq x(1-y) = x - xy \leq 1 - xy$
>  $0\leq  y (1-x) = y - xy \leq 1 - xy$.

Multiply these and we are done.

Comment: This is elegant and useful, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative proof using AM-GM

$$x(1-x)y(1-y)-(1-xy)^2=(x-x^2)(y-y^2)-(1-2xy+x^2y^2)\\
=xy-xy^2-x^2y+x^2y^2-1+2xy-x^2y^2=xy(3-x-y)-1 \\
\le \left(\frac{x+y+3-x-y}{3}\right)^3-1=0.\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 0):

This is
$x (1-x) y (1-y) \le (1 - xy)^{2}
$
or,
with help from Wolfy,
$(1 - xy)^{2}-x (1-x) y (1-y)
=1/4 y (2 x + y - 3)^2 + 1/4 (-y^3 + 6 y^2 - 9 y + 4)
\ge 0
$.

$-y^3 + 6 y^2 - 9 y + 4
=4-y(y^2-6y+9)
=4-y(y-3)^2
$
and for
$0 \le y \le 1$,
if $f(y) = y(y-3)^2$,
$f'(y)
=3 (y^2 - 4 y + 3)
=3(y-3)(y-1)
\ge 0$
for $0 \le y \le 1$.

Since
$f(0) = 0$
and $f(1) = 4$,
$-y^3 + 6 y^2 - 9 y + 4
\ge 0$
so
$(1 - xy)^{2}-x (1-x) y (1-y)
\ge 0
$.